# Scala Char automatically converts to Integer

Tags: scala

Char is automatically converted to Integer. Why did this conversion from char to Int happen?
I expected res2 to be of dataType anyVal.

```
val achar = 'a'
if (b > 12) 12 else achar
res2: Int = 97
```

Comment: @SethTisue ah yes you are right, is actually a ["view"](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/12-the-scala-standard-library.html) _(i.e. an implicit conversion)_. - Which, not sure if it is the mechanism used to ensure weak conformance.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you  return a Int Value in the true-branch. Scala behaves with those primitive datatypes just like java (the classes are transformed into primitives through the compiler). So the return type of your if could be either a char or a int (12 is a integer, because number literals are always integers). Since a char could not hold every int, the compiler "casts" your char to a int.
If you would cast `12` to a char like this:

```
val achar = 'a'
if (b > 12) 12.asInstanceOf[Char] else achar
```

It would return a char.

Comment: It's called "weak conformance": https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#weak-conformance